# Vertex Attributes in JGraphX

Tags: java, jgraphx

I'd like to know if there is a list of possible attributes (and their possible values) to use when creating a new vertex in JGraphX.

I know the method is `graph.insertVertex(parent, null, vertexText, 0, 0, width, height, "whiteSpace=wrap;fillColor=red")`; but I don't know which attributes can be put other than `whiteSpace` or `fillColor`. For example I need to add padding to the text in the vertexes, but I don't know how.

Any help would be appreciated; if I made any mistakes making the question, please tell me and I'll fix them ^^

Answer (score 0):

What you need can be found in mxConstants class:
https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx/blob/master/src/com/mxgraph/util/mxConstants.java

All the attributes (which is called vertex style) that can be used in vertex are defined in this class. If you want to change the style dynamically then you should use mxStylesheet.